# VueJs Pagination using laravel resource collection

Tags: vue.js, pagination

Building pagination with Resource Links not working as expected in vuejs.
Checking if data.links in return from Resource is not null be assigning class.

```
 <nav >
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item" :class="{'disabled': !products.links.prev , 'active': products.links.prev != null}">
                <a class="page-link" @click="getPrevPage" >Previous</a>
                </li>
                <span class="mr-3"></span>
                <li class="page-item" :class="{'disabled': !products.links.next, 'active': products.links.next != null}">
                <a class="page-link" @click="getNextPage" >Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

But I get error in Console

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prev' of undefined"
```

Previous and Next Implementation and find attached picture of data structure returned.

```
getNextPage(){
        this.loadProduct(this.products.links.next);
    },
    getPrevPage(){
    this.loadProduct(this.products.links.prev);
    },
```

[image: Response data returned]

Comment: Did you define this.products or products.links?

Comment: I have products in my data Object, So yes i have this.products
`data() {
     products: {}
}`
And that's the reason why I do the check in for nav binding the class
`:class="{'disabled': !products.links.prev , 'active': products.links.prev != null}"`

Comment: Can you provide the entire js code? Because this error means that some object here is not defined. If you try to console.log(this.products.links) this, tell me what you get.